# Rails Tagging: Find Tags by number of occurances

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I have a fairly simple tagging model in my app.

```
Photo has_many :taggings
Photo has_many :tags, :through => :taggings

Tag has_many :taggings
Tag has_many :photos, :through => :taggings

Tagging belongs_to :photo
Tagging belongs_to :tag
```

What I'd like to do now is retrieve all the tags, order them by the number of photos tagged with that particular tag, and show that number along side the tag.

How do you write a query like that? And, how do you prevent an n+1 query when you show `tag.photos.count` for each tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL is your friend** - assuming the `Tag` model has a `name` attribute:

```
tags = Tag.joins(:photos).
           group("tags.id").
           select("tags.id, tags.name, count(*) as num_photos").
           order("num_photos")

tags.all.each do |tag|
  puts [tag.id, tag.name, tag.num_photos].join(",")
end
```

You could throw that in a scope (e.g., `with_counts`) and do things like:

```
 Tag.where(["tags.name = ?",sassy]).with_counts.first.num_photos
```

Comment: Will rails automatically construct the join through `taggings` when you specify `joins(:photos)` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will, but there's an easy way to find out :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but assuming that all the Taggings are valid links between a tag and a photo you could use

```
Tagging.group("tag_id").order("count(*) desc").count
```

to get an ordered hash of all the Tag ids and the number of taggings/photos associated with that tag.